# Facebook page post schedule using python

Tags: python

I've just implemented the, add the post in Facebook page, but I want this post to schedule on after some time using python

code to post on page

```
page_access_token = "key"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
facebook_page_id = "page"
published = False
# Converting datetime object to string
now = datetime.now()

timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
graph.put_object(facebook_page_id, "feed", message='test messages')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sleep` function from `time` library in Python.

Comment: Or you can just use `cron` job if you are in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is creating a new post on Facebook.com and can be put inside a method say facebookPost(). You can use apscheduler library for scheduling your task.

> pip install APScheduler

For scheduling your post like below code.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def facebookPost():
    page_access_token = "key"
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
    facebook_page_id = "page"
    published = False
    # Converting datetime object to string
    now = datetime.now()

    timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
    graph.put_object(facebook_page_id, "feed", message='test messages')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('scheduler function start() called!')
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(facebookPost, 'interval', seconds=30)
    scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm looking for Bulk scheduling at time